# Opening Google Docs from Windows 10 File Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, google-docs, google-backup-and-sync

I am using Google Drive Backup and Sync for Windows 10. Google Docs open VERY slowly from File Explorer. With the Chrome browser already open, it takes about 30 seconds after opening the file from File Explorer for the new tab to appear and open the Google Doc. Is there a way to improve this?

Comment: I pinned Google Docs to the taskbar and it responds the same as opening the files. Backup and Sync 3.40.8921.5350. Windows 10 Pro Version 1709 Build 16299.371. I tried changing different default web browsers with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Basic troubleshooting on browser:

Clear your cache and cookies.

Try an incognito or private window.

Disable browser plugins or extensions. (Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer, and Safari instructions.)

Reset your Chrome settings.

Run Chrome Cleanup Tool, to remove software that may cause Chrome to experience issues

Next, click on Google Drive in the system tray > Preferences > Advanced.

By default, the Proxy setting is set at "Automatically detect proxy settings." Instead, tick "Direct connection."

Google Docs Help Forum

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/docs

Comment: Proxy set to direct connections and no bandwidth limitations. Clean installs of Firefox and Chrome (with no extensions) creates the same result. The issue does not seem to be with the web browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Opening the url stored in the gsheet file directly with your browser seems to allow the gsheet file to open and begin to load immediately. This [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1414015/1017832) describes how to do that. Note that there is a bug in that code and the corrected one is provided below.

```
 @echo OFF
    set CHROME_PATH=C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
    set fn=%1
    set fn=%fn:"=%
    python -c "import json;import subprocess;subprocess.run(['%CHROME_PATH%',json.load(open(r'%fn%'))['url']])"
```

Steps:

0. install [Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/)
1. save the code to a bat file
2. find a gsheet file
3. right click it
4. open with
5. choose another app
6. tick always use this app to open gsheet files
7. scroll down to the bottom and choose "look for another app on this PC"
8. select the bat file you made

One problem is that using a bat file as the default will make all gsheet files have a blank icon. To fix this, you have to convert the bat file to an exe file and set the icon, which can be done using this [program](https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/bat_to_exe_converter.html). To obtain the gsheet icon, follow these [steps](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/128170-extract-icon-file-windows.html). Note that this script and method can also be used to fix the slow load times with gdoc files, gslide files, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the CPU usage of "Antimalware Systems Executable" was increasing dramatically when I opened a .gdoc or .gsheet file from File Explorer. Adding an exclusion to Windows Defender improved the load time.

Go to Windows Security > Virus and Threat Protection > Manage settings > Add or remove exclusions > Add an exclusion > Process

Then enter the path to the Backup and Sync executable, e.g., "C:\Program Files\Google\Drive\googledrivesync.exe"